# How does ElasticSearch handle an index with 230m entries?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I was looking through elasticsearch and was noticing that you can create an index and bulk add items.  I currently have a series of flat files with 220 million entries.  I am working on Logstash to parse and add them to ElasticSearch, but I feel that it existing under 1 index would be rough to query.  The row data is nothing more than 1-3 properties at most.

How does Elasticsearch function in this case? In order to effectively query this index, do you just add additional instances to the cluster and they will work together to crunch the set?

I have been walking through the documentation, and it is explaining what to do, but not necessarily all the time explaining why it does what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to effectively query this index, do you just add additional instances to the cluster and they will work together to crunch the set?

That is exactly what you need to do. Typically it's an iterative process:

1. start by putting a subset of the data in. You can also put in all the data, if time and cost permit.
2. put some search load on it that is as close as possible to production conditions, e.g. by turning on whatever search integration you're planning to use. If you're planning to only issue queries manually, now's the time to try them and gauge their speed and the relevance of the results.
3. see if the queries are particularly slow and if their results are relevant enough. You change the index mappings or queries you're using to achieve faster results, and indeed add more nodes to your cluster.

Since you mention Logstash, there are a few things that may help further:

- check out [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-overview.html) for indexing the data on an ongoing basis. You may not need to do the work of reading the files and bulk indexing yourself.
- if it's log or log-like data and you're mostly interested in more recent results, it could be a lot faster to split up the data by date & time (e.g. index-2019-08-11, index-2019-08-12, index-2019-08-13). See the [Index Lifecycle Management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html) feature for automating this.
- try using the [Keyword field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) where appropriate in your mappings. It stops analysis on the field, preventing you from doing full-text searches inside the field and only allowing exact string matches. Useful for fields like a "tags" field or a "status" field with something like ["draft", "review", "published"] values.

Good luck!

Comment: one thing to note is that while you do not have a lot of fields, having a lot of different possible values (i.e. high cardinality) and many shards can impact how your cluster behaves both memory wise as well as general query performance which you may want to take into account in case of large cluster sizes (not sure this is the case due to the small amount of fields)

Comment: my data itself is static. Im trying to find an easier way to query it.  I just need to determine the correct means in which to pipe it into the elasticsearch.

Comment: What is your data @Fallenreaper ? Logstash is excellent for log-like data, but if you haven't used it then it could be a lot of work to learn and deploy for a one-off on static data. In that case bulk upload with a custom script e.g. Python may be faster overall.

Comment: @EmanuilTolev data i am looking at is huge, 130k flat files, and some csv. I dont mind using python for it, but it looks like if i give it a recursive directory of .txt files, it does same thing.  The issue I have now is that the ElasticSearch DB is in my vm which after 12 hours will run out of hard drive space.  So im not sure on whether or not it is better to increase the HDD size or try to get the elasticsearch db to point to my host shared folder, `/media/sf_shared/` as the location of the ES data repository.